# Create multiple relationships in Neo4j using array of integers using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and Cypher and have just imported two csvs - one is a list of places and the other is a list of people.

Each place has multiple peopleIDs for the people that have visited it stored as integers in an array.

Similarly, Each person has multiple placeIDs for the places they have visited stored as integers in an array.

I'm struggling when creating the relationships between the people and place nodes in my graph. I have tried the following, which works for individual IDs, but it doesn't create any relationships from an array of IDs:

```
MATCH (p1:People),(p2:Place)
WHERE p1.placeID = p2.placeID
CREATE (p1)-[:VISIT]->(p2)
```

The headers for the People csv file are as follows:
[image: People csv headers]

The headers for the Places csv file are as follows:
[image]

I guess that I need to use `FOREACH` or `UNWIND` or both but I can't find any good examples of how to achieve what I'm after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to track down a similar question to my one here, which provides an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861841/creating-relationships-based-on-array-values-in-neo4j)

To solve my question I've used the following:

```
MATCH (p1:People)
UNWIND p1.placeID as pID
MERGE (p2:Place{placeID: pID})
MERGE (p1)-[AT]->(p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not use the optimal strategy for importing the data. In a graph DB, it is not good practice to store data (like lists of IDs) that would *only* be used to create relationships later. That would leave you with a lot of redundant data that would never be used again (and ideally should be deleted).

A better strategy would involve 3 steps:

1. Import the nodes from the `People` file - but *ignore* the Place ID lists
2. Import the nodes from the `Place` file - but *ignore* the People ID lists
3. Import the relationships from one of the files (I assume it does not matter which). For example, I'll assume we pick the `Place` file, and that each file row has an `id` field with the ID of a Place and a `people` field containing a semicolon-delimited collection of People IDs. A query like this would then create all the needed relationships (and avoid creating duplicates):

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///places.csv' AS row
   MATCH (place:Place) WHERE place.id = row.id
   MATCH (person:People) WHERE person.id IN SPLIT(row.peopleIds, ';')
   MERGE (person)-[:VISIT]->(place)
   ```

Comment: Thank you - my plan was to discard the IDs once the relationships are built but I can see how my approach is sub-optimal. I’ll give the above a go later, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply - I've just been trying and have made some amends to fix the naming I'm using to the below: 
`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://localhost:11001/project-ca45d786-e360-4e3b-b4b4-eb8fe62a7b55/Places-Gridv2.csv' AS row
MATCH (place:Place) WHERE place.id = row.id
MATCH (nickname:People) WHERE nickname.id IN SPLIT(row.peopleID, ';')
MERGE (nickname)-[:VISIT]->(place)`

However, when I run it, no relationships are created.

Comment: Have added them to the original question above

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. Try changing `WHERE place.id = row.id` to `WHERE place.id = row.placeID`.

Comment: Thanks, the query still isn't building any relationships though

Comment: Do your `People/Place` nodes actually have `id` properties, or are they using some other property name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216676/discussion-between-sean-and-cybersam).